# web3.eth.getAccounts() does not return all addresses

Tags: web3js, metamask

so I'm trying to retrieve all the account addresses that are currently present on MetaMask.
So I tried to do that using `window.web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)` but that seems to be returning just an array of size with the current address selected in MetaMask. Is there anyway I could get all the accounts?[image]

Comment: It's a security feature of Metamask. It only exposes the account you have selected after you agreed via the GUI.

Comment: Okay. So is there any other way I could retrieve all the accounts?

Comment: So I found this: "We plan to allow the `eth_accounts` array to be able to contain multiple addresses in the near future." on [MetaMask Docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#events) under the `accountsChanged` event does this mean that it could potentially allow more than 1 account to be retrieved using the `getAccounts()` function